# args [] for file read

Tags: java, args

I have a question regarding to String[] args use in Java:

```
     ......
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new EMR().start(args);
}

public void start(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File recordFile = new File(args[0]);
    File instructionFile = new File(args[1]);
    File outputFile = new File(args[2]);
    .......
```

That is just an example for file read, so if I want to run the code and put actual file name/path to the main() method, how can I achieve it, for instance, can I write it like :

```
    new EMR().start(1.txt,2.txt.3.txt)
```

Comment: Add it as an argument to the command line, or change the command line arguments in the startup configuration if you're using an IDE.

Comment: How are you currently executing the application?

Comment: Hi Jeroren, thanks for reply, for example, can I write it as new EMR().start(1.txt,2.txt.3.txt);

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here; what's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Hi Matt, I need to put actual file name or path to the main method to execute it with eclipse

Comment: Oli Charlesworth, I just do not know how to execute it, to run the program, I need to put actual txt file in to the main method for program to read in, I am not sure how to code it

Answer (score 1):

If you change yo varargs you can write

```
new EMR().start("1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt");

public void start(String... args) throws IOException {
```

Or without changing start you can write

```
new EMR().start("1.txt 2.txt 3.txt".split(" "));
```

Comment: Hey Peter, thank you for help, what does split(",")mean, does it mean for args input, I cannot code , for command line input?

Comment: @peiwang The command already splits by space. In Java is is more natural to split by `,` or similar. Updating the example to split by space as the command line does

Answer (score 1):

pass argument on command line like this

```
C:\myfolder> java HelloWorld hi java world
```

where **HelloWorld** is java Class Name and **hi java world** are args for e.g: hi = args[0] , java = args[1] , hello = args[2]